# Running Batch From C# Application

Tags: c#, node.js, batch-file, pm2

I have this batch file which store in C Drive called stop.bat.

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO STOP ALL APPLICATIONS
call pm2 stop all
PAUSE
```

Any I tried to run this batch from winform application.

```
 // var cmd = "/K pm2 stop all";
 // Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmd);
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\stop.bat");
```

in my command line

```
child_process.js:120
  p.open(fd);
    ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, uv_pipe_open
    at Object._forkChild (child_process.js:120:5)
    at Object.setupChildProcessIpcChannel (internal/process/main_thread_only.js:124:30)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:134:23)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

When I manually open stop.bat, it run success, however, it didn't do anything when calling from code.

Comment: Is this maybe related? https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2037
Issue looks to be more with pm2 than running from C#

Comment: `EBADF` occurs when you don't close `fd`. If you have any instance of same `fd` running, try closing and rerun the code.

Comment: C# doesn't do anything special. [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) is an interface on top of the Windows' process API. In fact, the batch doesn't really do except call `pm2` with some arguments. The same can be done with `Process.Start("pm2","stop all")`, assuming `pm2` can be found in the system's path. That won't fix any `pm2` bugs though

Comment: @Oliver, I found out that there is no way i can fix that bug. So I go back using window function to start and kill the task

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right. it's pm2 bug so i have to find that bug in pm2.

Comment: If the batch runs when started from Windows (double click) it must also be able to be run from C#. Have you checked if it is a matter of current working directory either by setting it from C# (`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`) or in the batch file by adding the first line `cd /d %~dp0`

Comment: @sa.he it still giving me same problem. I change to window service and use taskkill to kill the process.

Comment: i have tried with powershell too, it appears same errors